# Dynamic model based on JSON received from web service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I am creating a MVC web application which receives some data from a web service in JSON format. I get the different content type structures and data items related to that structure. Using that JSON I want to allow users to create new items in specific content type or edit item.

Now the problem is that I do not know the structure of item, there may be n number of structures. I want to create a ViewModel dynamically on runtime for this purpose.

Is it possible or there should be any other approach?

Answer (score 1):

JSON.NET has a nice approach for this. It provides different ways to deal with this issue. See [Serializing and Deserializing JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm).

There are method resulting in a type called `JObject` which has methods allowing you to traverse the resulting model.